# Zend Framework 2 - Showing the content of a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, zend-framework2

I'm making some kind of market site with Zend Framework 2. The home got a slider showing all the products (realized with CSS3 keyframes) and some text. Both the sliding pictures and the text are read from a MySQL database. But as result, i get no output but also no errors. The slider gets as many pictures as database rows, but still no content is echoed; plus if i try to change things (like db credentials or getter functions in model) it throws errors as expected, so it clearly reads the db and the problem is elsewhere.

Db for text has 3 fields:
id
name
text

Model for text (Home.php; there's an HomeInterface.php defining all the functions)

```
<?php    
namespace Site\Model;    

class Home implements HomeInterface {
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $text;


    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getText() {
        return $this->text;
    }
}
?>
```

Mapper for text

```
<?php    
namespace Site\Mapper;    

use Site\Model\HomeInterface;    
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;    
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;    
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorInterface;    
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\HydratingResultSet;    
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;    
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;    

class TextMapper implements TextMapperInterface {    
    protected $homePrototype;    
    protected $adapter;    
    protected $hydrator;    

    public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter, HomeInterface $homePrototype, HydratorInterface $hydrator) {    
        $this->adapter = $adapter;    
        $this->homePrototype = $homePrototype;    
        $this->hydrator = $hydrator;    
    }    

    public function find($name) {    
        $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);    
        $select = $sql->select();    
        $select->from("mono");    
        $select->where(array("name = ?" => $name));    
        $stmt = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);    
        $result = $stmt->execute();    

        if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult() && $result->getAffectedRows()) {    
            return $this->hydrator->hydrate($result->current(), $this->homePrototype);    
        }    

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("{$name} non esiste.");
    }    
}    
?>
```

Mapper for text has a factory, since it has dependencies:

```
<?php
namespace Site\Factory;

use Site\Mapper\TextMapper;    
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;    
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;    
use Site\Model\Home;    
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;    

class TextMapperFactory implements FactoryInterface {    
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {    

        return new TextMapper($serviceLocator->get("Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter"), new Home(), new ClassMethods(false));    
    }    
}    
?>
```

Service for text:

```
<?php    
namespace Site\Service;    

use Site\Model\Home;    
use Site\Model\HomeInterface;    
use Site\Mapper\TextMapperInterface;    

class HomeService implements HomeServiceInterface {    
    protected $textMapper;    

    public function __construct (TextMapperInterface $textMapper) {    
        $this->textMapper = $textMapper;    
    }    
    public function findText($name) {    
        return $this->textMapper->find($name);    
    }    
}    
?>
```

Factory for this service:

```
<?php    
namespace Site\Factory;    

use Site\Service\HomeService;    
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;    
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;    

class HomeServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface {    
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {    
        $textMapper = $serviceLocator->get("Site\Mapper\TextMapperInterface");    
        return new HomeService($textMapper);    
    }    
}    
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php    
namespace Site\Controller;    

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;    
use Site\Service\HomeServiceInterface;    
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;   

class SkeletonController extends AbstractActionController {    
    protected $homeService;    

    public function __construct(HomeServiceInterface $homeService) {    
        $this->homeService = $homeService;    
    }    

    public function indexAction() {    
        return new ViewModel(array (
            "home" => $this->homeService->findText("home")    
        ));    
    }    
}    
?>
```

Finally, the view:

```
<?php echo $this->home->getText(); ?>
```

Code for slider is similar and both the parts of this page are likely having the same problem. As i said, db is detected, tables and columns too, they aren't empty but nothing gets echoed. Interfaces are properly written, defining all the functions. All views are in the Site\view\Site\Skeleton folder. Any clues about where the problem is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good. The only issue I can see is that you are using the `ClassMethods` hydrator and you have no setters on your entity.

The hydrator [will use the entity API to hydrate the entity, if the `setId`, `setName` or `setText` are not callable then the values will not be set](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-stdlib/blob/master/src/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php#L212).

Although I recommend adding the missing methods you can also use the `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\Reflection` to set the entity properties without setters (via [SPL `ReflectionProperty`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionproperty.php))

Comment: So you're saying the ClassMethods() forces me to add setter methods? Can i leave them empty for a while, until i'm good to design all the user part?

I'll try to do it with Reflection as well, although this project will need an admin sidelater

Comment: You will need to add them for it to work for the `ClassMethods` hydrator.

Comment: It looks insignificant, but it works well. Thank you for your help